# How to start the default Android Downloads Activity or App?

Tags: android

My app saves a file in the default downloads folder. Which is determined by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`.

Now I want open thee default Android Downloads Activity or App, so the user sees the downloads folder with my new file.

Comment: Unless you used `DownloadManager`, your file will not appear in the Downloads app, at least on most versions of Android, IIRC. The Downloads app traditionally has shown only the files that it downloaded, not the entire contents of any given `Downloads/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this method.

```
public void openFolder() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder"); 
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need [DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)

```
Intent viewDownloadsIntent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
startActivity(viewDownloadsIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
startActivity(intent);
```